# iOS-Charts chart doesn't drawn because xAxis values (Date type) not sorted

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I'm using version 3.0.2 for Swift 3. to draw a `LineChartView`

I have this format for the date from the api as `String` : `"2017-11-04 16:48:55"`

```
["2017-11-09 14:22:54","2017-11-09 14:22:07","2017-11-09 14:21:20","2017-11-04 18:58:01","2017-11-04 16:48:55","2017-11-04 16:35:00"]
```

So I convert the string to date through formatter

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00")

let date = dateFormatter.date(from: updatedAt)
let timeInerval = date?.timeIntervalSince1970
let dateInSeconds = Int(timeInerval!)
dates.append(Double(dateInSeconds))
```

If I printed the dates array I'll get:

```
[1510237374.0, 1510237327.0, 1510237280.0, 1509821881.0, 1509814135.0, 1509813300.0]

let dateFormatterForXAxis = DateValueFormatter()
chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = dateFormatterForXAxis
```

where DateValueFormatter class:

```
import Foundation
import Charts

class DateValueFormatter: NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter {
    var dateFormatter: DateFormatter!

    override init() {
        dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h"
    }

    func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        return dateFormatter.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: value))
    }
}
```

The chartView haven't drawn, because the values not sorted.
When I sort `dates` I got very odd chart.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: FYI - `timeIntervalSince1970` gives you a value in seconds since the epoch, not hours.

Comment: @rmaddy typo :), this's not biggest concerns right now!